# Ignore controller in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

Our team maintains a self-hosted ASP.NET Web API. The project uses attribute routing and we have dozens of existing controllers. Lets say, the API is exposed via the main path `/api/purpose1/...` with all the existing controllers being placed as resources underneath.

Now I want to introduce a new parallel main path, e. g. `/api/purpose2/`. It should be possible to activate both main paths independently of each other via a boolean variable in a config file.

Since all the controllers are within one assembly, the attribute routing approach always finds and adds them to both `purpose1` and `purpose2`. This contradicts the independency of `purpose1` and `purpose2`. So I used attribute routing for `purpose1` and convention-based routing for `purpose2`. That at least worked, but I'm not happy with the mixture of two different routing approaches.

So my question is: can I disable certain controller classes with attribute routing?

Comment: Please check [IControllerActivator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.icontrolleractivator?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [IControllerFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.icontrollerfactory?view=aspnetcore-3.1) interfaces. Implementing these can give you full control over controller creation.

Comment: Alternatively you could override the [OnActionExecuting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method of the Controller to examine the feature flag.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you, I will take a look at this. Do I have to implement both interfaces?

Comment: IControllerFactory should be enough. I'll provide an example.

Comment: Which .net core or .net framework version are you using?

Comment: Great! We're using .NET Framework 4.6.2

Comment: [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/732449/Understanding-and-Extending-Controller-Factory-i-3) you can find a quite neat implementation. Please bear in mind that `DefaultContollerFactory` is **internal** in .NET Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Peter Csala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61674567/4919526) is fine, however, it has a dependency to `System.Web.Mvc`. In our case, this dependency wasn't there before and I found a solution that does not require adding it.

I've extended [`ApiControllerActionInvoker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh835986(v=vs.118)) the following way:

```cs
internal class CustomHttpActionInvoker : ApiControllerActionInvoker
{
    public CustomHttpActionInvoker(IConfigProvider configProvider)
    {
        ConfigProvider = configProvider;
        InvokeActionFunc = base.InvokeActionAsync;
    }

    /// <summary>FOR AUTOMATED TESTS ONLY</summary>
    internal CustomHttpActionInvoker(IConfigProvider configProvider,
                                     Func<HttpActionContext, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> invokeActionFunc)
    {
        ConfigProvider = configProvider;
        InvokeActionFunc = invokeActionFunc;
    }

    private IConfigProvider ConfigProvider { get; }

    private Func<HttpActionContext, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> InvokeActionFunc { get; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var isRelevantRequest = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller is MyRelevantController;
        if (isRelevantRequest && ConfigProvider.IsPurpose1)
        {
            return InvokeActionFunc(actionContext, cancellationToken);
        }

        if (!isRelevantRequest && ConfigProvider.IsPurpose2)
        {
            return InvokeActionFunc(actionContext, cancellationToken);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }
}
```

The `internal` constructor was introduced to support easier unit testing.

The following code registers the custom class:

```cs
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionInvoker), new CustomHttpActionInvoker(MyConfigProvider));
```

Answer (score 2):

### OnActionExecuting example:

#### V1 controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SampleV1Controller : VersioningAwareControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new OkObjectResult("V1");
    }
}
```

#### V2 controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SampleV2Controller : VersioningAwareControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new OkObjectResult("V2");
    }
}
```

#### Versioning aware base controller

```
public abstract class VersioningAwareControllerBase: ControllerBase, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (!FeatureFlags.ShouldDeprecateV1 ||
            !string.Equals(context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), "samplev1",
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return;

        context.Result = NotFound();
        context.Canceled = true;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { }
}
```

Comment: That looks good, I will try this. However, I'm curious how an example of  `IControllerActivator` and `IControllerFactory` would look like

Comment: Please check these two articles to get better insight: [IControllerActivator](https://andrewlock.net/controller-activation-and-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core-mvc/), [IControllerFactory](http://www.jomendez.com/2016/01/20/how-to-create-custom-controller-factory-asp-net/)